# Div container margin isn't staying relative to the previous div

Tags: css, html

Ok I have  a problem where one div's margin doesn't appear to stay relative to the previous div as the browser window re-sizes (height not width). This creates the problem where content overlaps as shown when in a wide browser. The picture bellow shows how in a narrow screen it works fine, however in the second picture you can see how the div has moved up based on the browser being made wider (27 inch imac).

[image: Narrow Screen]

[image]

If you go to: http://creativeabyss.co.uk/test/ you can see this effect for your self as you resize the window (You might need a big monitor). I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this, so I was wondering if any of you could help? The code should be available at the aforementioned link.

p.s I have set the background of one div to blue which illustrates that it is the size of this div which appears to be causing the issue...

Comment: How big a monitor are we talking?  Also, what browser?

Comment: I'm testing using chrome, the overlap occurs when the browser is set to the full width of my 27inch iMac. You can see how the "ABOUT ME" section moves though just by changing the browser size a little.

Comment: Let me rephrase, what resolution are you seeing this at?  I tried on Firefox 20 at 1280x1024 and it seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the fixed height on `#OuterMenu`. It is set to `300px`, when you resize the browser window, the height of the content inside `#OuterMenu` decreases, but `#OuterMenu` is still `300px` high, this causes some empty white-space to be displayed before the content which is rendered below it. Getting rid of the fixed height on `#OuterMenu` will fix this. It breaks on high resolutions because then the content inside `#OuterMenu` will be too high for its containing `div` which is only `300px` high. In this case it will look like the content below this `div` is rendering over the top of the content inside `#OuterMenu`, but in fact it is the `300px` height set on `#OuterMenu` which is limiting the space allowed for `#OuterMenu` to render its content within.

Comment: Spot on - this nailed the problem on the head. Can't believe I didn't spot this! Thank-you for you help.